# Android - end fragment activity

Tags: android

What is the equivalent of

```
finish()
```

for a fragment activity in

```
OnPause();
```

I cant find it anywhere, I just want the fragment to end when it is paused

Answer (score 10):

As others have already stated, call finish() as you would in a regular Activity.  In regards to the onPause() part of your question, I'm not sure what you are looking for, but it might be a good idea to review the lifecycles of Activities and Fragments...

**Activity Lifecycle**

[image]

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

**Fragment Lifecycle**

[image]

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle

Comment: if you go into a fragment classes onpuase() and type finish() it will not work

Answer (score 10):

call this line and it will kill the current fragment

```
getActivity().finish();
```

Comment: hmm .. what's the news compared to earlier answers?

Comment: it will kill the activity. the question is how to kill the fragment but not the activity

Answer (score 1):

You can still use finish(). FragmentActivity extends Activity

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html

Comment: I am not in a fragment activity I am in a fragment

Comment: You can call getActivity() to get the parent activity

Comment: I am using a navigation drawer, the way a nav drawer works is there is one activity that swaps out fragments when something is selected, so if i kill the activity I kill the app, how can I just kill the fragment?

Answer (score 1):

A `FragmentActivity` is extended from an `Activity`, so you can still use the `finish()` call to end your class.

Comment: I am using a navigation drawer so i cant end the activity I need to just end the fragment